# How do I write separate log files for each Log level in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

My current logging setup creates a file for application messages and cli message.  How would I get it to create a separate file for each of the different log levels (DEBUG, ERROR, etc...)?

My app/start/global.php config is like this:

```
$logFile = 'log-'.php_sapi_name().'.txt';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);

App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use something like that:

```
$handler = new Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler(storage_path().'/logs/info.log',0,Logger::INFO);
Log::getMonolog()->pushHandler($handler);
```

If you want it for errors use Logger::ERROR etc.

For Documentation of the __construct:
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php